# Improve performance of drawing with Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am using matplotlib to plot more than one hundred of graphs. This is currently too slow and I'd like to optimize the code a bit.

Each figure contains up to 20 lines that am drawing this way (simplified):

```
f, ax = plt.subplots(1)
for i, y in enumerate(data):
    ax.plot(tasks, res, marker=markers[i], label=labels[i])
```

I suppose that the method `plot` is actually drawing too much stuff (such as the axis). I tried using `line.set_ydata` but this replaced the previous line.

Is there a way to do something similar but faster?

Comment: Have you profiled this?  `ax.plot` only adds the artists to the axes, it does not trigger a re-rendering of the graph.  Looping and adding 500 lines to an axes takes ~400ms, rendering that takes ~1.7s.  I don't think that there is enough code here to reproduce your problem.

Comment: perhaps instead of creating a new figure each time, create 1 figure and clear it (`clf`) before new overall iteration.